# I want to change the web ad displayed in the user's browser through the Android app

Tags: android, ads

I want to do something, but I don't know how doing it.
I can't even figure out which keyword to search on Google, so I ask the following questions:
I'm not good at English, so this question was written in my native language and translated into Google Translator. My sentence may be awkward, so please understand.

//==============================================

Currently, I have developed an Android application and placed it on the Play Store.
It's hard to say what my app is doing specifically, and let's assume it's an app that sells apples.

I'm making money by selling apples directly from my app, but I want to get some advertising revenue from Google and other advertising companies.

I could place an ad directly in my application, but I want to:

You'll find ads appearing on Google or third-party billboards on various web pages, such as articles on journalist web pages or personal blogs. There will be ads from apple sellers, too.

When a user uses a phone which my app is installed accesses a web page with a billboard like this, I want to increase the number of advertisements about apple sellers.
It doesn't matter whether it's our company or another company's ad.

And because of my application, for consumers who need an apple, ads from apple sellers are more likely to appear, so I'd like to get a portion of the advertising fees paid by apple sellers to advertisers.

However, I am not sure if there is an internet advertising company that runs such an advertising system, so I would like to know if there is such a company and system.
And I want to know the technical details of changing the display of my ads, too,

Long answers are also welcome, but if you simply throw a keyword or link, I'll look for it and study it. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not that easy, but here is how you can do it:
Since you are using WebView you must interrupt the html before the browser can parse it. You have to manipulate the html and replace it with your ads. Lets say you do this with Admob or Adsense , then you have to replace the ID's(pub and block). You can also run javascript to do this on the webview once the webpage is fully loaded.

But beware what you are going to do is not compliant to the policy of play store and it will get you banned.

Comment: Because of the policy of playstore, I can't do that. But Thanks a lot!